# Track Block Pattern Insertion Within the Block Editor

Tags: block-editor

Our team is looking for a way to track when block patterns are inserted into the WordPress block editor. We would also like to record the name of the block pattern that's being inserted. This tracking will help us better understand which patterns provide the most value to our clients, and where we might need to make changes.

The method we need to hook into is `insertBlocks()` (https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-block-editor/#insertblocks) since the `meta` parameter passes the name of the block pattern during insertion.

The pull request at https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/25165 shows the WordPress team built in a way to do this, but they didn't provide direction on "how".

I'm no expert with React and Redux, so any help on how best to do this would be great. Even a little bump in the right direction would be awesome. Thanks a ton for your help.